# History of the notion of irreducible representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ho.history-overview, harmonic-analysis

I am looking for the earliest references where the study of irreducible representations appears. There has been many articles and books on the history of representation theory. A fundamental feature of this theory, is that in good situations where one is dealing with a semisimple category, one can decompose objects into simple ones, or here, irreducible representations. My understanding is that the introduction of this circle of ideas is usually credited to Frobenius around the end of the 19th century.

However, the decomposition of tensor products of irreducible representations of $SL_2$ can be found in the article by Paul Gordan ["Beweis, dass jede Covariante und Invariante einer binären Form eine ganze Function mit numerischen Coefficienten einer endlichen Anzahl solcher Formen ist."](https://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002153793) in J. reine angew. Math. **323** (1868), 323-354.
It is written in old fashioned language that can be difficult to decipher, but the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition for $SL_2$ is basically there in Section 2 of that article. One could also ask: when was it realized that it was important and very useful to decompose general representations in terms of irreducibles? Reading the proof in that article, one can only conclude that Gordan was very well aware of that.

Also note that for the irreducible representations for $SL_n$, one can find a description already in the article by Alfred Clebsch ["Ueber eine Fundamenthalaufgabe der Invariantentheorie"](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN250442582_0017?tify=%7B%22pages%22:[167],%22view%22:%22toc%22%7D), in
Abhandlungen der Königlichen Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften in Göttingen **17** (1872), 3-62, and its shorter follow-up ["Ueber eine Fundamentalaufgabe der Invariantentheorie"](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002241978), Math. Ann. **5** (1872), 427-434.

Are there earlier references about irreducible representations?

Comment: You have done well already with this.  A related question is how did characters of representations first arise?  Back in the 1980's when Mike Hopkins and I were working on our generalized character theories applied to complex oriented cohomology theories, Mike was looking at the 19th century representation theory literature, to see when it was realized that characters were telling you about G-modules. G for us was finite, and 40 years later, we still don't really know what an irreducible module in Morava E-theory means, even though we know what the characters look like.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Do you remember what Mike excavated from his archeological dig in the 19th century literature?

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: Nice! Indeed, a covariant of degree $n$ and order $k$ of a binary form of degree $d$, in modern language is the same as an element of ${\rm Hom}_{SL_2}(S_k, {\rm Sym}^n(S_d))$ or intertwiner. Here $S_p$ is the $p+1$-dimensional irreducible representation of $SL_2$. So I guess the earlier work of Cayley, etc. on covariants secretly involves irreducibles.

Comment: Perhaps this should be migrated to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user347489 Research-level questions belong here.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler as you know HSM has some fantastic Q and A for all type of questions related to history of mathematics, including some that could be considered research level. Has this already been discussed in the meta? I personally believe this belongs there, but I also understand how this falls into a gray area.

Comment: @user347489 I don’t know that.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @user347489: I also subscribed and contributed to hsm.stackexchange but I asked the question on MO for a reason. I am primarily interested in the input of professional mathematicians. I would not mind having the question cross-posted on hsm but I am against simply migrating the question to hsm.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: You raised some very good points. But it goes in a direction which is different (more analytic) from how I thought about the question (more combinatorial and category theoretic in flavor). I would have to amend my post to reflect that, but I can't do it now. Too much work.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: I just saw you added the "harmonic-analysis" tag (which is totally fine by me) but that's what I was trying to say in my previous comment: I would prefer the point of view of representation theory rather than harmonic analysis...if one could separate the two...BTW I think you should collect what you said in the comments and write an answer which would certainly deserve some upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

I convert my comments to an answer per Abdelmalek’s request:

1. Dieudonné [attributes](//mathoverflow.net/a/337130) the classification of irreducible $sl_2$-modules to Cayley (1856).
2. Also the theory of spherical and cylindrical harmonics should qualify as prehistory — told in e.g. Heine ([1878](//mathoverflow.net/a/219112), pp. 1–10), Burkhardt ([1902–1903](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PID=PPN37721857X_0010_02_01), Chap. V).
3. The *words* “irreducible” and “degree” hint at another root: if $G$ is finite, decomposing its regular representation $L$ on $\mathbf C[G]$ (elements $x=\smash{\sum x_g\delta^g}$, product $\smash{\delta^g\cdot\delta^h}=\smash{\delta^{gh}}$, $L(x)y=x\cdot y$) amounts to [factoring](//zbmath.org/?q=an:27.0094.01) the “group determinant” $\det(L(x))$ into irreducible polynomials in the $x_g$.

(“When was it realized that it was important and very useful to decompose general representations in terms of irreducibles?” inadvertently evokes a whole other question involving the origin of Fourier analysis, going back to at least D. Bernoulli, not to mention celestial epicycles, Pythagorean ideas on musical harmony; or Lang’s *Algebra*’s casting of Jordan form as “Representation Theory of One Endomorphism” (or the monoid algebra $k[\mathrm X]$ of $(\mathbf N,+)$, with irreducibles etc.) — but I understand the intent was to keep it non-commutative.)

Comment: Great!...thank you.